# how to kill android application on back pressed in Sherlock list fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-listfragment

as application starts main activity called which redirect to FragmentOne class which implements SherlockListFragment.

when i click back initially onpause() called and returns home screen.

on next run, let say initially four fields are there

When i click on create button, it creates a new field and redirect to my main activity that to Fragment one which shows updated 5 fields

now if i press back button, onpause() called and it goes to last FragmentOne that shows four field

again pressing back button shows home screen

Now i want to kill the app when it is on FragmentOne and presses back button

Answer (score 0):

System.exit(0) would do the job. use them at approriate places